# jQuery accessing form array

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php form and I want to display or hide certain fields dependant on what I select in a drop down.
I have code below which works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.pupname').hide();
    $('div.pupnid').hide();

    if ($("#perpetrator").val == "1") {
        $('div.pupname').hide();
        $('div.pupid').show();
        else {
            $('div.pupid').hide();
            $('div.pupname').show();
        }

        $("#perpetrator").change(function() {
            if ($("#perpetrator").val() == "1") {
                $('div.pupname').hide();
                $('div.pupid').show();
                else {
                    $('div.pupid').hide();
                    $('div.pupname').show();
                }
            });

        });
```

I now want to have a multi row block which I am generating using php so I can generate the divs as *pupid1*, *pupid2* etc. and the field `$m_perpetrator` as an array.  I've tried a few ways of accessing the array but can't get anything to work.  I thought he following might be along the correct lines for accessing the elements of the array but it does nothing.

```
if ($("#m_perpetrator[1]").val == "1") {
    $('div.pupname1').show();
    $('div.pupid1').hide();
}
else {
    $('div.pupid1').show();
    $('div.pupname1').hide();
}
```

Added

Here is a snippet of the HTML

```
<td><select name="m_perpetrator[1]" id="m_perpetrator[1]">
<option value="1">Current</option>
<option value="2" selected>Former</option>
<option value="3">Parent/Carer</option>
</select>
</td> 
<td>Name</td>
<td>
<div class="pupname1">
<input type="text" size=60 name="m_pupil_name[1]" value="JOHN SMITH">
</div>

<div class="pupid1">
<select name="m_pupil_id[1]"  onchange="getXtras(this)">
<option value="">Select .....</option>
```

So basically this is a multi row form and on each row if Current is selected then I want to display pupil_id if anything else is selected then I want to display pupil name.
For processing the input I run round the array m_perpetrator[] using php
Jim

Comment: Show us the HTML that the PHP is producing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not completely sure what you need. Do you have multiple elements with the same id m_perpetrator?

Use class instead you should do it this way

```
if ($($(".m_perpetrator")[1]).val() == "1") {
    $('div.pupname1').show();
    $('div.pupid1').hide();
}
else {
    $('div.pupid1').show();
    $('div.pupname1').hide();
}
```

Otherwise what is m_perpetrator in html?

Comment: As you can see from the "#" in the selector, m_perpetrator is an id. It is not valid HTML to use the same id for multiple elements, nor will it work with jQuery. Your suggestion to use a class instead would work, though.

Comment: Here is a snippet of the HTML

Comment: <td><select name="m_perpetrator[1]" id="m_perpetrator[1]">
<option value="1">Current</option>
<option value="2" selected>Former</option>
<option value="3">Parent/Carer</option>
</select>
</td> 
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>
   <div class="pupname1">
   <input type="text" size=60 name="m_pupil_name[1]" value="JOHN SMITH">
   </div>
      
   <div class="pupid1">
   <select name="m_pupil_id[1]"  onchange="getXtras(this)">
   <option value="">Select .....</option>

Comment: So basically this is a multi row form and on each row if Current is selected then I want to display pupil_id if anything else is selected then I want to display pupil name.

Comment: For processing the input I run round the array m_perpetrator[] using php.

Comment: @Jin Please **edit** your question with the information you're posting in the comments

Comment: As Geon said, [] are not a good idea for html id. If you can use m_perpetrator1 instead, everything's gonna work

Comment: I've got a solution to work based on Mauro's last comment.  It's not as elegant as I had hoped but it now works. Thanks very much for all of your help.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use "[" or "]" in the id attribute. I'd suggest you output a list element like this:

```
<ul id="whatevers">
    <li><input name="whatever1" /></li>
    <li><input name="whatever2" /></li>
    <li><input name="whatever3" /></li>
<ul>
```

You can then access them with jquery like this:

```
var ws = $("#whatevers input");
for(var i=0; i< ws.length; ++i){
    ws.eq(i).doSomething();
}
```